# Оттформатировать код по горячей клавише

Tags: android, shortcuts

По какой горячей клавише сделать вот так отформатированный код

```
<RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

вот из такого кода:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: вопрос максимально непонятный, что-то где-то нажимается, что-то нужно разнести, добавьте конкретики пожалуйста

Comment: для форматирования в одну строку есть комбинация Smart line join CTRL+SHIFT+J, а вот как наоборот из одной строки отформатироват в разные строки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы "причесать" код и отформатировать его, можно использовать сочетание клавиш:

```
windows - CTRL+ALT+L 
mac - Command+Option+L
```

Как сказано [здесь](https://medium.com/mindorks/11-android-studio-shortcuts-every-android-developer-must-know-a153e736e611#:%7E:text=Android%20Studio%20takes%20care%20of,all%20the%20code%20for%20you.) и [здесь](https://ayusch.com/must-know-android-studio-tips/). Это сочетание клавиш выровняет ваш код